# How can I filter DataFrame by column value(string) be cotained by a const string

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe(data) like:

```
              mac  len      corp                               detail
18025    14:1F:BA    8  IeeeRegi          IEEE Registration Authority
18026  14:1F:BA:0   10  Shenzhen  Shenzhen Mining Technology Co.,Ltd.
18027  14:1F:BA:1   10   Gloquad                                  NaN
18028  14:1F:BA:2   10  Deutsche      Deutsche Energieversorgung GmbH
18029  14:1F:BA:3   10   Private                                  NaN
```

I wanna use a const str to filter data where data['mac'] is contained in str.
such as if str is "14:1F:BA:14:E4:5E", the result is row 18025 and 18027.

How do i do it ?

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
# df is your dataframe
Str = "14:1F:BA:14:E4:5E"

#filter the dataframe by condition: df.mac is contained in Str
df_filtered = df[df.mac.apply(Str.startswith)]
```

If you would like to get indexes, you can use `index`:

```
result = df_filtered.index
```

Comment: `x in` will match anywhere in the string, not only at the beginning.

Comment: @StephenRauch, fixed

Comment: This is faster `df[["14:1F:BA:14:E4:5E".startswith(x) for x in df.mac.values.tolist()]]`

Comment: This is cleaner and faster `df[df.mac.apply("14:1F:BA:14:E4:5E".startswith)]`

Comment: Great! It's very efficient and clean.

Comment: @piRSquared, why `df[df.mac.apply("14:1F:BA:14:E4:5E".startswith)]` is faster?

Comment: Because `pandas` doesn't have to figure out what the `lambda` is doing.  I tested it out over a larger dataframe.  With lambda: 17.4 ms.  Without: 10.6 ms.  I didn't post my own answer because you were the one who first posted the use of `str.startswith` with in a looping structure.  It is my opinion that what I'm proposing is an improvement on your answer and that you deserve the credit.  That's why I'm making a comment and upvoting your answer.

Comment: @piRSquared, yes, your method is faster. My tests show `376 ms` VS `204 ms`. Thanks)